# Pass through vertex shader for texture mapping?

Tags: opengl, glsl

I added a vertex shader to [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3585515/807893):

```
void main()
{   
    gl_Position = ftransform();
}
```

then I get this image:

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For texture mapping using a vertex shader you will also need to pass the texture coordinates as well as the vertex positions to the fragment shader.  Examples, including the one below, can be found [here](http://nehe.gamedev.net/article/glsl_an_introduction/25007/)

```
void main()
{
    // Transforming The Vertex
    gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex;

    // Passing The Texture Coordinate Of Texture Unit 0 To The Fragment Shader
    texture_coordinate = vec2(gl_MultiTexCoord0);
}
```

Comment: Blech! Use swizzle notation.  I like gl_MultiTexCoord0.xy, because I don't believe in .st; it doesn't convey meaning to me.  uv would be appropriate, but GLSL doesn't support it.