# OpenGL Application Code in relation to GLSL

Tags: c++, opengl

I am having some difficulty understanding the connection between my OpenGL application and my GLSL files (.vert and .frag). I know how to create a vertex or fragment shader, and there is plenty of examples on the web, but I am having difficulty actually using my shader within my application, specifically, linking (binding?) textures to my shader. My question is, what code am I missing to use the textures I have uploaded into my application with the shader?

My current application creates a window, loads 4 textures (rock, grass, stone, and a mixmap since I want to use this for texture splatting), and then draws a quad in the main loop. My entire code for the application is below:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <glew.h>
#include <gl/gl.h>
#include <gl/glu.h>

#include "textfile.h"
#include "textfile.cpp"

using namespace std;

class Scene {
public:
    void resize( int w, int h ) {
        // OpenGL Reshape
        glViewport( 0, 0, w, h );
        glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
        glLoadIdentity();
        gluPerspective( 120.0, (GLdouble)w/(GLdouble)h, 0.5, 500.0 );
        glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
    }
};

///Shader
GLuint p, f, v;
void setShader() {

    char *vs,*fs;

    v = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    f = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    vs = textFileRead("shader.vert");
    fs = textFileRead("shader.frag");

    const char * vv = vs;
    const char * ff = fs;

    glShaderSource(v, 1, &vv,NULL);
    glShaderSource(f, 1, &ff,NULL);

    free(vs);free(fs);

    glCompileShader(v);
    glCompileShader(f);

    p = glCreateProgram();

    glAttachShader(p,v);
    glAttachShader(p,f);

    glLinkProgram(p);
    glUseProgram(p);
}

int main() {

    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600, 32), "Test");

    ///Setup the scene, materials, lighting
    Scene scene;
    scene.resize(800,600);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glColorMaterial(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_EMISSION);
    glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);

    ///Terrain Textures
    sf::Image tex0;
    tex0.loadFromFile("mixmap.png");
    sf::Image tex1;
    tex1.loadFromFile("grass.png");
    sf::Image tex2;
    tex2.loadFromFile("rock.png");
    sf::Image tex3;
    tex3.loadFromFile("stone.png");

    GLuint mixmap;
    glGenTextures(1, &mixmap);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, mixmap);
    glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE);
    glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
    glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, tex0.getSize().x, tex0.getSize().y, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (const GLvoid*)tex0.getPixelsPtr() );

    GLuint grass;
    glGenTextures(1, &grass);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, grass);
    glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE);
    glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
    glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, tex1.getSize().x, tex1.getSize().y, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (const GLvoid*)tex1.getPixelsPtr() );

    GLuint rock;
    glGenTextures(1, &rock);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, rock);
    glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE);
    glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
    glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, tex2.getSize().x, tex2.getSize().y, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (const GLvoid*)tex2.getPixelsPtr() );

    GLuint stone;
    glGenTextures(1, &stone);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, stone);
    glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE);
    glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
    glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, tex3.getSize().x, tex3.getSize().y, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (const GLvoid*)tex3.getPixelsPtr() );

    ///I am afrain I am missing some code here that will actually link the textures to the shader itself

    ///Shader
    glewInit();
    setShader();

    ///Start loop
    while( window.isOpen() ) {
        sf::Event event;
        while( window.pollEvent( event ) ) {
            if( event.type == sf::Event::Closed )
                window.close();
        }

        glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();
        gluPerspective(50.0, 1.0, 1.0, 50);
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glLoadIdentity();
        gluLookAt(1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0);

        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
            glVertex3f(-0.5, -0.5, 0.0);

            glVertex3f(-0.5, 0.5, 0.0);

            glVertex3f(0.5, 0.5, 0.0);

            glVertex3f(0.5, -0.5, 0.0);
        glEnd();

        ///Reset env settings for SFML
        glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE);

        window.display();
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Below are my vertex and fragment shaders as well, though I am unsure if my vertex shader is complete...

Vertex:

```
void main()
{
 gl_TexCoord[0] = gl_MultiTexCoord0;
 gl_Position = ftransform();
}
```

Fragment:

```
uniform sampler2D MixMap;
uniform sampler2D Grass;
uniform sampler2D Stone;
uniform sampler2D Rock;

varying vec4 texCoord;

void main(void)
{
   vec4 mixmap   = texture2D( MixMap, texCoord.xy );
   vec4 tex0    = texture2D( Grass, texCoord.xy ); 
   vec4 tex1    = texture2D( Rock,  texCoord.xy ); 
   vec4 tex2    = texture2D( Stone, texCoord.xy );

   tex0 *= mixmap.r; 
   tex1 = mix( tex0, tex1, mixmap.g ); 
   vec4 outColor = mix( tex1, tex2, mixmap.b ); 

   gl_FragColor = outColor;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you'll need to bind each texture object to a texture unit in the OpenGL context. GPUs have `GL_MAX_COMBINED_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS` number of texture image units, each of which can have textures attached to it.

This would look like this:

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + 0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, mixmap); //mixmap now attached to sampler 0

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + 1);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, grass); //attached to sampler 1

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + 2);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, rock);  //attached to sampler 2

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + 3);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, stone); //attached to sampler 3
```

Note the `GL_TEXTURE0` + *x* syntax. This is done so that you don't feel constrained by `GL_TEXTUREi` only going up to `GL_TEXTURE32`; you can have more than 32 simultaneous multi-textures (if your implementation supports it). Granted, I don't know why you would want to, but you can.

Now you have four textures bound to four texture image units. The next step is to assign the GLSL samplers to texture image units. After you have linked your shader, you must query the uniform location of each sampler, and then tell the program which texture image unit it should look for for the actual texture.

```
compileAndLinkProgram();
glUseProgram(program);

mixmapUniformLocation = glGetUniformLocation(program, "MixMap"); //get the uniform associated with "MixMap"
glUniform1i(mixmapUniformLocation, 0); //set MixMap uniform to 0 (sampler 0);


grassUniformLocation = glGetUniformLocation(program, "Grass"); //get the uniform associated with "Grass"
glUniform1i(grassUniformLocation, 1); //set Grass uniform to 1 (sampler 1);

...repeat for 4 samplers...
```

Now when you sample a sampler in the shader, it will pull from the texture bound to that sampler.

Comment: You do not attach a texture to a sampler. You *bind* a texture to a texture image unit in the context, then tell the program that it's sampler(s) use particular texture image units in the context. It is an indirect association.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas Would you be willing edit the correct terminology? I'm afraid I don't quite understand the difference between a sampler and texture image unit. Even the [OpenGL wiki](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Texture_Sampling) seems to be ambiguous *"but make sure you bind the texture to the correct sampler with glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE14)"*

Comment: Thank you for alerting me to that wiki page so I can nuke it. In the future, you may want to refer to [this section](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLSL_Sampler#Binding_textures_to_samplers) for more accurate info.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use both [glGetUniformLocation](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGetUniformLocation.xml) and [glUniform](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glUniform.xml) to tell the shader program which textures are attached to which samplers.

Examples here:
[Multiple textures in GLSL - only one works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3569261/multiple-textures-in-glsl-only-one-works)

Comment: Not entirely accurate. glUniform doesn't tell the shader program which textures are attached to which samplers. It tells the shader which sampler variable, e.g. *Grass*, *Stone* is assigned to which sampler index. `glActiveTexture/glBindTexture` assign textures to sampler units.