# How can I pass multiple textures to a single shader?

Tags: opengl, glsl, texture-mapping, texture2d, opengl-2.0

I am using freeglut, GLEW [and DevIL](http://r3dux.org/2011/09/simple-texture-loading-with-devil-revisited/) to [render a textured teapot](http://www.lighthouse3d.com/tutorials/glsl-tutorial/combine-texture-fragment/) using a vertex and fragment shader. This is all working fine in OpenGL 2.0 and GLSL 1.2 on Ubuntu 14.04.

Now, I want to apply a bump map to the teapot. My lecturer evidently doesn't brew his own tea, and so doesn't know they're supposed to be [smooth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Original_Utah_Teapot.jpg). Anyway, I found [a nice-looking tutorial on old-school bump mapping](http://content.gpwiki.org/index.php/OpenGL:Tutorials:GLSL_Bump_Mapping) that includes a fragment shader that begins:

```
uniform sampler2D DecalTex; //The texture
uniform sampler2D BumpTex; //The bump-map
```

What they don't mention is *how* to pass two textures to the shader in the first place.

Previously I

```
//OpenGL cpp file
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureHandle);

//Vertex shader
gl_TexCoord[0] = gl_TextureMatrix[0] * gl_MultiTexCoord0;

//Fragment shader
gl_FragColor = color * texture2D(DecalTex,gl_TexCoord[0].xy);
```

so now I

```
//OpenGL cpp file
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureHandle);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, bumpHandle);

//Vertex shader
gl_TexCoord[0] = gl_TextureMatrix[0] * gl_MultiTexCoord0;
gl_TexCoord[1] = gl_TextureMatrix[1] * gl_MultiTexCoord1;

//Fragment shader
gl_FragColor = color * texture2D(BumpTex,gl_TexCoord[0].xy);
//no bump logic yet, just testing I can use texture 1 instead of texture 0
```

but this doesn't work. The texture disappears completely (effectively the teapot is white). I've tried GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, glActiveTexture and few other likely-seeming but fruitless options.

After sifting through the usual mixed bag of references to OpenGL and GLSL new and old, I've come to the conclusion that I probably need `glGetUniformLocation`. How exactly do I use this *in the OpenGL cpp file* to pass the already-populated texture handles to the fragment shader?

- [How to pass an array of textures with different sizes to GLSL?](https://www.gamedev.net/topic/589024-how-to-pass-an-array-of-textures-with-different-sizes-to-glsl/)
- [Passing Multiple Textures from OpenGL to GLSL shader](https://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/163092-Passing-Multiple-Textures-from-OpenGL-to-GLSL-shader?p=1152122&viewfull=1#post1152122)
- [Multiple textures in GLSL - only one works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3569261/multiple-textures-in-glsl-only-one-works)

(This is homework so please answer with minimal code fragments (if at all). Thanks!)

*Failing that, does anyone have a tea cosy mesh?*

Comment: I am using multiple textures in GLSL from python. Here is my [repo with screenshots](https://github.com/cprogrammer1994/heightmap-multitexture-terrain)

Answer (score 76, accepted):

It is very simple, really. All you need is to bind the sampler to some texture unit with [`glUniform1i`](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glUniform.xml). So for your code sample, assuming the two uniform samplers:

```
uniform sampler2D DecalTex;  // The texture  (we'll bind to texture unit 0)
uniform sampler2D BumpTex;   // The bump-map (we'll bind to texture unit 1)
```

In your initialization code:

```
// Get the uniform variables location. You've probably already done that before...
decalTexLocation = glGetUniformLocation(shader_program, "DecalTex");
bumpTexLocation  = glGetUniformLocation(shader_program, "BumpTex");

// Then bind the uniform samplers to texture units:
glUseProgram(shader_program);
glUniform1i(decalTexLocation, 0);
glUniform1i(bumpTexLocation,  1);
```

OK, shader uniforms set, now we render. To do so, you will need the usual [`glBindTexture`](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glBindTexture.xml) plus [`glActiveTexture`](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/1.1/docs/man/glActiveTexture.xml):

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + 0); // Texture unit 0
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, decalTexHandle);

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + 1); // Texture unit 1
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, bumpHandle);

// Done! Now you render normally.
```

And in the shader, you will use the textures samplers just like you already do:

```
vec4 a = texture2D(DecalTex, tc);
vec4 b = texture2D(BumpTex,  tc);
```

Note: For techniques like bump-mapping, you only need one set of texture coordinates, since the textures are the same, only containing different data. So you should probably pass texture coordinates as a [vertex attribute](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Attribute).

Comment: excellent! it was the order of glGetUniformLocation/glUseProgram/glUniform1i that was my main point of confusion - as mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/a/12065077/236081 I had to `glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + 0);` after the final glBindTexture for it to work - and thanks for the khronos links

Comment: How do glGenSampler and GlBindSampler involve in this procedure?

Comment: `GL_TEXTURE0 + 1 == GL_TEXTURE1` for anyone wondering

Answer (score 4):

instead of using:

```
glUniform1i(decalTexLocation, 0);
glUniform1i(bumpTexLocation,  1);
```

in your code,
you can have:

```
layout(binding=0) uniform sampler2D DecalTex;  
// The texture  (we'll bind to texture unit 0)
layout(binding=1)uniform sampler2D BumpTex;   
// The bump-map (we'll bind to texture unit 1)
```

in your shader. That also mean you don't have to query for the location.

Comment: This is not correct for GLSL 1.2 because the "layout(location=0)" does not exist.

Comment: I would argue this is elegant solution in modern Opengl. Using the "layout" binding gives one the ability to bind texture cords and the texture index from your vertex data (glVertexAttribPointer()), older openGL standards are VERY far out of favor. and doing this gives your shader the ability to select the correct index out of a group of samplers.

Comment: Perhaps and I generally agree with you, @Pnelego, but to be fair, we mean very modern--layout (binding) wasn't introduced until GLSL version 4.2. I'm personally working on a project where I'm targeting 3.3, just for the sake of flexibility, and can't count on that.

Comment: Also OpenGL 4.5 adds the simpler glBindTextureUnit() instead of having to set glActiveTexture() each time before your glBindTexture() calls.