# What is the correct way to bind Multiple Textures on OpenTK?

Tags: c#, textures, fragment-shader, opentk

I tried to implement a simple test program following the OpenTK official tutorial ([here](https://opentk.net/learn/chapter1/6-multiple-textures.html)) but I can't achieve any result.
Following the exact coding sequence proposed my output is just a white square. I tried several patches such as avoiding the fragment shader mix() function and what I found is that the tutorial-proposed code transferred to the fragment shader only the last loaded texture.

In particular, the proposed code lets you generate a texture and assign attributes without binding the texture, while I found some answers that suggest the binding should happen before assigning any attribute (for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3569261/multiple-textures-in-glsl-only-one-works)).

So I tried any combination of GL function calls, and I still don't have a working code, but some insights (my latest code below):

- if I load a texture by activating the Texture Unit before, it consistently assigns texture regardless the texture object creation order, however only `TextureUnit.Texture0` seems to reach the fragment shader and be assigned to any declared sampler2D
- calling the `GL.GetUniformLocation` and subsequent `GL.Uniform1()` to assign the uniform indexes doesn't produce any visible change in the behaviour
- changing the position where I call `GL.UseProgram(shader.Handle)`; doesn't make any difference
- as mentioned above, the fragment shader function `texture(tex0, texCoord)` shows the first texture, and so the `texture(tex1, texCoord)` or any other declared sampler
- the `mix(texture(tex0, TexCoord), texture(tex1, TexCoord), 0.2);` fragment shader function shows always white pixels, even when mixing the same texture calling `mix(texture(tex0, TexCoord), texture(tex0, TexCoord), 0.2);` (note that such texture show up instead when I call `texture(tex0, texCoord)`)

I run out of ideas and I can't find any resources.
Thanks for helping.

**Fragment Shader Source:**

```
#version 330 core

in vec2 texCoord;
out vec4 outputColor;

uniform sampler2D tex0;
uniform sampler2D tex1;
uniform sampler2D tex2;

void main() {
    //outputColor = mix(texture(tex0, TexCoord), texture(tex1, TexCoord), 0.2);
    outputColor = texture(tex0, texCoord);
    //outputColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

**Vertex Shader Source:**

```
#version 330 core

layout(location = 0) in vec3 aPosition;
layout(location = 1) in vec2 aTexCoord;

out vec2 texCoord;

void main(void)
{
    texCoord = aTexCoord;
    gl_Position = vec4(aPosition, 1.0);
}
```

**Texture Class Source:**

```
internal class Texture {

public int Handle { get; private set; }

public Texture(string sourceFile, TextureUnit unit = TextureUnit.Texture0)
{

    Image<Rgba32> image = Image.Load<Rgba32>(sourceFile);
    image.Mutate(x => x.Flip(FlipMode.Vertical));
    var pixels = new byte[4 * image.Width * image.Height];
    image.CopyPixelDataTo(pixels);

    GL.ActiveTexture(unit);

    this.Handle = GL.GenTexture();
    GL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.Texture2D, this.Handle);

    GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureWrapS, (int)TextureWrapMode.Repeat);
    GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureWrapT, (int)TextureWrapMode.Repeat);
    GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureMinFilter, (int)TextureMinFilter.Linear);
    GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureMagFilter, (int)TextureMagFilter.Linear);

    GL.TexImage2D(
            TextureTarget.Texture2D,     // Texture type
            0,                           // Level of detail
            PixelInternalFormat.Rgba,    // GPU storing format
            image.Width, image.Height,   // Width, Height
            0,                           // Border of the image, legacy param
            PixelFormat.Rgba,            // Format: ImgSharp use this
            PixelType.UnsignedByte,      // Pixel type
            pixels);                     // Actual pixels
}

[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
public void Use()
{
    GL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.Texture2D, this.Handle);
}

//[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
public void Use(TextureUnit unit)
{
    // GL.ActiveTexture(unit);
    // GL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.Texture2D, this.Handle);
}

} // Texture Class
```

**Shader Class Source (only relevant methods):**

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
public void Use()
{
    GL.UseProgram(program);
}

[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
public void SetInt(string name, int value)
{
    int location = GL.GetUniformLocation(program, name);
    GL.Uniform1(location, value);
}
```

**Loading method of the game class:**

```
    protected override void OnLoad()
    {
        GL.ClearColor(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1.0f);

        VertexArrayObject = GL.GenVertexArray();
        VertexBufferObject = GL.GenBuffer();
        ElementBufferObject = GL.GenBuffer();

        // 1. bind Vertex Array Object
        GL.BindVertexArray(VertexArrayObject);

        // 2. copy our vertices array in a buffer for OpenGL to use
        GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, VertexBufferObject);
        GL.BufferData(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, vertices.Length * sizeof(float), vertices, BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw);

        // 3. then set our vertex attributes pointers
        GL.VertexAttribPointer(0, 3, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, 5 * sizeof(float), 0);
        GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        GL.VertexAttribPointer(1, 2, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, 5 * sizeof(float), 3 * sizeof(float));
        GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(1);

        // Indices to ElementBufferObject
        GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer, ElementBufferObject);
        GL.BufferData(BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer, indices.Length * sizeof(uint), indices, BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw);

        shader = new Shader("./ShadersSrc/vshader6_textures2.glsl", "./ShadersSrc/fshader6_textures2.glsl");

        texture0 = new Texture("./Textures/src/container.jpg", TextureUnit.Texture0);
        shader.SetInt("tex0", 0);

        texture1 = new Texture("./Textures/src/awesomeface.png", TextureUnit.Texture1);
        shader.SetInt("tex1", 1);
        
        texture2 = new Texture("./Textures/src/wall.jpg", TextureUnit.Texture2);
        shader.SetInt("tex1", 2);

        base.OnLoad();
    }
```

**Frame drawing method of the game class:**

```
    protected override void OnRenderFrame(FrameEventArgs e)
    {
        GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit);

        GL.BindVertexArray(VertexArrayObject);

        shader.Use();
        //texture0.Use(TextureUnit.Texture0);
        //texture1.Use(TextureUnit.Texture1);

        GL.DrawElements(PrimitiveType.Triangles, indices.Length, DrawElementsType.UnsignedInt, 0);

        Context.SwapBuffers();

        base.OnRenderFrame(e);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GL.Uniform1()`  sets the value of a uniform variable in the standard uniform block of the current program object. Therefore, you must install the program with `GL.UseProgram` before you can set a uniform:

```cs
shader.Use();
shader.SetInt("tex0", 0);
shader.SetInt("tex1", 1);
```

Comment: Nevermind, I found the problem and I feel dumb: typo error on the "TexCoord" variable.